# How to revoke the access and refresh token in Oauth2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I've used this method for revoke the token. But the access token and refresh token again reusable. How to revoke the access and refresh token?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Revoke(string 
   refreshToken,stringaccessToken){
    var identityService = await 
    DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

    var revocationClient = new 
    TokenRevocationClient(identityService.RevocationEndpoint, "ro.client", 
    "secret"); 
    var response = await 
    revocationClient.RevokeRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken); 
               var response1 = await 
    revocationClient.RevokeAccessTokenAsync(accessToken);
}
```

Comment: Are you using reference tokens or JWTs? Revocation only works for the former

Comment: I'm using JWT tokens for revoke

Comment: Thanks, Mackie. Now I change JWT tokens to reference token. What are the changes in the config and startup files? Can you help me? or sent any reference links?

Comment: I don't want to be the RTFM guy but it's explained here:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html

You're APIs will need to be able to call the introspection endpoint to validate said reference tokens so you'll need to ensure they have a secret defined and that the middleware is configured suitably.

Comment: how to expire Jwt token manually expiry? Is it possible?

Comment: I change reference token type. That time I can't access the API call. I think startup or config file any mistake does.

Comment: The link post by @mackie is broken, the new link is: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html.

Answer (score 1):

Only reference and refresh tokens can be revoked in this way. JWTs are valid until their exp time unless you build additional logic into the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

My company, who provide software for managing investment banking assets, use the following separation:

**API CREDENTIALS**

- Access tokens are for calling APIs from UIs
- They have a short lifetime of 30 minutes
- They are JWTs and do not need to be revoked since they are short lived

**USER SESSIONS**

- These are represented by a refresh token
- The refresh token for a UI might last for 8 hours
- Every 30 minutes the access token expires and is silently renewed
- Refresh tokens are stored in a database
- An IT administrator can revoke a refresh token by deleting it from the DB
- This will force a new login after no more than 30 minutes

**REVOCATION PROCESS**

- Typically the IT administrator will want to use context when revoking a refresh token, such as Application Id, User Id and Time Issued
- So if you are providing a UI for revocation you might want to provide fields such as the above

Comment: Gary, What type of UIs are you using? Browsers or some kind of desktop or mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

refresh tokens are only used for desktop / mobile apps or for server side web apps.

For a true browser app (single page app) you can't use refresh tokens. You can still separate API credential time from User Session time though.

There are some notes on my blog around sessions, in case they help:

- [OAuth Token Renewal Messages](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/)
- I'm not covering server side web apps but basically they carry the refresh token around in the authentication cookie